# java7 G1 Options

Tags: java, g1gc

I can't find any options relating to how G1 operates. The below two commands no longer work with java7.

```
-XX:+G1ParallelRSetUpdatingEnabled 
-XX:+G1ParallelRSetScanningEnabled
```

Answer (score 3):

Only options I am aware of that have an impact on G1 are:

- to activate:

  `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC`
- to set the max GC pause time goal in milliseconds that G1 will attempt to meet:

  `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=<X>`
- to set the time interval over which GC pauses totaling up to MaxGCPauseMillis may take place:

  `-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=<X>`
- to set the size of the young generationto impact evacuation pause times:

  `-XX:+G1YoungGenSize=512m` *(also disabled in some versions)*
- to set the (not specific to G1 only) survivor spaces' size

  `-XX:SurvivorRatio=6` *(and other survivor-related options)*

### Quick Warning

Be warned that all -XX options types are deemed experimental and subject to change at any time (so, usually not stuff you want to stick in the `.{bat,sh}`, `wrapper.conf` script or config file used to jump-start your enterprise application.

They are pretty useful, but not to rely on too much if you want a stable and durable launcher.

---

The 2 options you mentioned, while originally available at the time of G1's first public release in the course of Java SE 6 Updates, have now been deprecated. So has `G1YoungGenSize` in some versions.

---

**Sources:**

- [Java SE 6 Update 14 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u14-137039.html)
- [G1 Garbage First Collector Introduction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html)
- [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)
- Plus a [presentation on JVM Tuning](http://www.slideshare.net/giladgaron/hotspot-jvm-tuning)

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 update 4 now "fully supports" the G1 garbage collector, but it seems those parameters are no longer available. :(

These links shed some more light on the allowed JVM flags:

[Description of the G1 GC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/G1.html)

[JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#G1Options)